# Drupal google api markermanager

Tags: drupal, google-maps-api-3, markermanager

One of the website i'm managing is getting in trouble...And as i didn't develop this one, i had real problems to do something on it.

It's based on Drupal 7 and use the Getlocations module to set-up some Gmaps with marker.

The problem is that from last week, for some page, the maps is showing an unknow location (somewhere in spain...). But, when you move the map with arrow, it's get to the good location. The problem is totally random, hard to reproduce in exact condition etc...

Here is the javascript console :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '20' of undefined markermanager.js:534
```

This line is relative to the z parameter.

So, after looking on the net it appears that it could help to set up the version of maps in the call. Set the v variable to 3.9.

I opened the file : 
sites/all/modules/getlocations/getlocations.module and to this part :

```
$query = array();
if (! empty($key)) {
$query['key'] = $key;
}
$query['sensor'] = 'true';
$query['language'] = $language->language;
```

add this line :

```
$query['v'] = '3.9';
```

uploaded the news file, empty drupal and chrome cache then...nothing. Drupal still calling

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
key=xxxxxxxx;sensor=false&amp;language=fr"></script>
```

and does'nt specify the version...I look to other files in modules/getlocations and find nothing interesting.

So my question is : how can i specify the version number of gooleapis ? I'd like to call this :

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9&
key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx;sensor=false&amp;language=fr"></script>
```

I never use drupal and i'm dubitative on this point...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There is an [updated version of the Marker Manager](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markermanager/1.1/) that works with API v3.10.  Might be a better solution that hard coding the API version to a version that will probably be retired in 6 months.

Comment: I'll have a look. I know it's useless to hard code but it was to see if it's arrange the problem because it's really hard to define and so to find why it happens...Thanks.